# regular expressions, path from windows to linux in specific situations

Tags: regex, eclipse, directory, replaceall

I am trying to change the path delimiter from windows to linux-style, but only in specific code lines.
To find the specific lines is no problem, but I wand to automate the replacing.

IDE: eclipse

Every Path to change has a copy statement, for example:
 `copy "path\to\..\file.cpy"`.

Regex to search: `(copy[\s]+")[(..|[\w]+)[\\]]+(.cpy")`

Problem, I get only the start and end of a line: $1 is the **copy "** part, the $2 is the **.cpy"** part. I have no clue how to get the multiple folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need this kind of pattern that uses the `\G` feature that succeeds at the start of the string or at the position after the previous match:

```
pattern: ((?:\G(?!\A)|copy\s+")[^\\"]*)\\
replacement: $1/
```

details:

```
( # capture group 1
    (?: # non capturing group with two possible starts
        \G     # contiguous to the previous match or the start of the string
        (?!\A) # disallow the start of the string to match
      |      # OR   
        copy\s+" #"# first match
    )
    [^\\"]* #"# all that isn't a backslash or a double quote
)
\\ # the literal backslash
```

At the beginning (before the first match) the first branch fails (because of the `\G` assertion), only the second branch can succeed. Once done, the first branch is able to succeed.

Once the last backslash is reached, the contiguity is broken (ie: the first branch can't succeed no more and the only way for the pattern to succeed is the second branch. etc.

Note: if you want to ensure that your path ends with the `.cpy` extension, you need to add this condition with a lookahead assertion in the second branch:

```
((?:\G(?!\A)|copy\s+"(?=[^"]\.cpy"))[^\\"]*)\\
```

Comment: Thanks, never saw the \G feature before